# Rails Template Output Spacing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application.html.erb I have:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
  <link href="/assets/css-reset.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/globals.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap-2.3.1/css/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/assets/home_screen.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/home_screen.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="wvpCKeGQlyowV18CYU4V2Vn7f+IxHTK0zSkB2XVGajc=" name="csrf-token" />
```

How can I add output spacing for such results?

```
  <link href="/assets/css-reset.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/assets/globals.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/assets/bootstrap-2.3.1/css/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/assets/home_screen.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/home_screen.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
  <meta content="wvpCKeGQlyowV18CYU4V2Vn7f+IxHTK0zSkB2XVGajc=" name="csrf-token" />
```

Comment: By changing how Rails generates the output or post-generation beautification; it's just iterating over a collection and doesn't know about your initial indentation. Not that this should matter much.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
stylesheet_link_tag("application", :media => "all").split("\n").join("\n  ")
```

but you really think it worth the trouble?

You can see your HTML properly indented with firebug or something. Also this is more bytes to load while getting your webpage.